Hiding bones in 3d viewport only

I am trying to pose a model, but I only want the bones to be displayed in the orthographic views. Having the bones visible in the 3d port makes it difficult to see exactly what the pose looks like. Currently I am having to toggle the bones on and off to be able to do this, is there a way to switch off the bone display in the 3d port only?
I am using Blender version 4.2
Thanks.

It is not possible in Quard view.
But if you split view into separate views, you can hide armatures by object type:


Hi this solution works for me, further splitting the views essentially allows me to manually set a quad view where I can see all 3 orthographic views while still being able to control the overlays independetly. Thank you!

The best thing you can do in this case is to enable the filter button in the top right to be able to hide objects in the viewport:

From there you should be able to toggle this on or off using the newly added button in the outliner. It might also be a good idea to place your armature in a collection to easily toggle the whole collection instead.
